# iPhone iOS is there an open source side scrolling game I can take a look at?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-engine, side-scroller

I'm thinking of building a simple side scrolling game where an airplane is flying forward at constant speed and the user controls up and down to avoid obstacles. Since I have 0 game development experience, **I'm looking for an open source game project that I can modify to get a side scrolling game similar to the pic below.**

[image: Harrier attack]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/24155/how-to-make-a-side-scrolling-beat-em-up-game-like-scott-pilgrim-with-cocos2d-part-1). There is a link, final project at the end from where you can download full source.